# HighChart overlap columns but with two groups

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On the following [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/q8Udk/364/) I have made a chart with overlapping columns. But now all the columns in a chart are overlapped. I am presenting two group. These groups I don't want to over lap.

For overlapping I have used:

```
 plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    grouping: false,
                    shadow: false
                }
            }
```

This is what i want to achieve. 
[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/

Comment: I don't want to stack the columns. I want to overlap the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if you want the second column to be on the tick or in one category. If on the tick, then the above answer should do it otherwise [here](http://jsfiddle.net/quxf7Lfz/).
Point placement and point padding do the trick.

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,0.5)',
        data: [150, 200],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.1
    }, {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.5)',
        data: [140, 130],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.1
    }, {
        name: 'Profit',
        color: 'rgba(248,161,63,0.5)',
        data: [183.6, 189],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.1,

    }, {
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.5)',
        data: [203.6, 190],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.1,

    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the distance between "stacks" by [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement) param.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Stockholm - Sweden',
            data: [149.9, 171.5, 106.4 ],
            pointPlacement: 0.5
        }, {
            name: 'Linköping - Sweden',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5],
            pointPlacement: 0.5
        },
        {
            name: 'Hamburg - Germany',
            data: [183.6, 718.8, 918.5]
        },
        {
            name: 'Berlin - Germany',
            data: [831.6, 718.8, 981.5]
        }]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/egbna6q8/